# Can I define a MediaLibraryService without an app?

Tags: android, android-service, androidx, media-library

I want to define a [MediaLibraryService](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3) in such a way that Android Auto, Exoplayer, AIMP For Android and other apps can access and play the media my service manages.

I don't see a need for a UI/Activity. I just want to define a foreground service, and have the various front-ends find it.

I am trying to figure out if that is a reasonable approach. Can I just do that, or do I need to make a full app, with an activity with a MediaController/MediaBrowser in it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Media3 provides you with all the tools and APIs necessary to make the service its own standalone music player, so that controllers like Android Auto can access your music and play it, without the actual need for activities and other things. This means that you store your playlists on the service-side, you do everything on the service-side, and if you're willing to make a music player app, the activity can grab information from the service using APIs that are available by Media3 such as `getChildren`...etc

The powerful thing about the library is that you can `sendCustomCommand` which contain bundles of pretty much everything you need, this would prove helpful when you want to communicate between an activity and the service, but it's completely unnecessary when the app is being navigated via a controller like Android Auto and not the actual mobile app. A song is defined by its MediaId, so I believe that's all you need to make a song playable, also, services provide you with an `applicationContext` so you can query MediaStore all you want, and use Datastore or SharedPreferences all you want as well.

Here's an example MusicLibraryService which you can reference from (this is a bit of an advanced case where I am using two separate playlists (a tracklist and an actual playlist, both of which can be queued separately depending on which one the user picks from), also, it's a MedialibraryService so the hierarchy is very important. The very top-level parent root item is invisible, but it's extremely capital to the functionality of the service, because the whole hierarchy propagates from it, you can include mediaitems right below it if you're having one huge playlist, but the more levels of hierarchy you have the more complicated it gets. I suggest you take it step by step and get yourself familiarzed with MediaLibraryService using one root item and have children below directly first:

```kotlin
class MusicPlayerService : MediaLibraryService() {

    lateinit var player: Player
    private var session: MediaLibrarySession? = null

    private val serviceIOScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private val serviceMainScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    /** This is the root item that is parent to our playlist.
     *  It is necessary to have a parent item otherwise there is no "library" */
    val rootItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setMediaId(nodeROOT)
        .setMediaMetadata(
            MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .setIsBrowsable(false)
                .setIsPlayable(false)
                .setMediaType(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_FOLDER_MIXED)
                .setTitle("MyMusicAppRootWhichIsNotVisibleToControllers")
                .build()
        )
        .build()

    val subroot_TracklistItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setMediaId(nodeTRACKLIST)
        .setMediaMetadata(
            MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .setIsBrowsable(true)
                .setIsPlayable(false)
                .setMediaType(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_FOLDER_MIXED)
                .setTitle("Tracklist")
                .setArtworkUri(
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://mpappc/drawable/ic_tracklist")
                )
                .build()
        )
        .build()

    val subroot_PlaylistItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setMediaId(nodePLAYLIST)
        .setMediaMetadata(
            MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .setIsBrowsable(true)
                .setIsPlayable(false)
                .setMediaType(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_FOLDER_MIXED)
                .setTitle("Playlist")
                .setArtworkUri(
                    Uri.parse("android.resource://mpappc/drawable/ic_tracklist")
                )
                .build()
        )
        .build()

    val rootHierarchy = listOf(subroot_TracklistItem, subroot_PlaylistItem)


    var tracklist = mutableListOf<MediaItem>()
    var playlist = mutableListOf<MediaItem>()

    var latestSearchResults = mutableListOf<MediaItem>()

    /** This will fetch music from the source folder (or the entire device if not specified) */
    private fun queryMusic(initial: Boolean = false) {
        val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
        val src = sp.getString("music_src_folder", "") ?: ""

        serviceIOScope.launch {
            scanMusic(applicationContext, uri = if (src == "") null else src.toUri()) {
                tracklist.clear()
                tracklist.addAll(it)

                if (initial) {
                    serviceMainScope.launch {
                        player.setMediaItems(tracklist)
                    }
                }

                session?.notifyChildrenChanged(nodeTRACKLIST, tracklist.size, null)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        restorePlaylist(applicationContext) {
            playlist.clear()
            playlist.addAll(it)

            session?.notifyChildrenChanged(nodePLAYLIST, playlist.size, null)
        }

        /** Building ExoPlayer to use FFmpeg Audio Renderer and also enable fast-seeking */
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext)
            .setSeekParameters(SeekParameters.CLOSEST_SYNC) /* Enabling fast seeking */
            .setRenderersFactory(
                DefaultRenderersFactory(this).setExtensionRendererMode(
                    DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER /* We prefer extensions, such as FFmpeg */
                )
            )
            .setWakeMode(C.WAKE_MODE_LOCAL) /* Prevent the service from being killed during playback */
            .setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true) /* Prevent annoying noise when changing devices */
            .setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.DEFAULT, true)
            .build()

        player.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL

        //Fetching music when the service starts
        queryMusic(true)

        /** Listening to some player events */
        player.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
            override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
                super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)

                //Controlling Android Auto queue here intelligently
                if (mediaItem != null && player.mediaItemCount == 1) {
                    val playlistfootprint = mediaItem.mediaMetadata.extras?.getBoolean("isplaylist", false) == true

                    if (playlistfootprint && playlist.size > 1) {
                        val index = playlist.indexOfFirst { it.mediaId == mediaItem.mediaId }
                        player.setMediaItems(playlist, index, 0)
                        setPlaybackMode(PlayBackMode.PBM_PLAYLIST)
                    }

                    if (!playlistfootprint && tracklist.size > 1) {
                        val index = tracklist.indexOfFirst { it.mediaId == mediaItem.mediaId }
                        player.setMediaItems(tracklist, index, 0)
                        setPlaybackMode(PlayBackMode.PBM_TRACKLIST)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
                error.printStackTrace()

                Log.e("PLAYER", error.stackTraceToString())
            }
        })

        /** Creating our MediaLibrarySession which is an advanced extension of a MediaSession */
        session = MediaLibrarySession
            .Builder(this, player, object : MediaLibrarySession.Callback {
                override fun onGetItem(session: MediaLibrarySession, browser: MediaSession.ControllerInfo, mediaId: String): ListenableFuture<LibraryResult<MediaItem>> {
                    return super.onGetItem(session, browser, mediaId)
                }

                override fun onSetMediaItems(
                    mediaSession: MediaSession,
                    controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
                    mediaItems: MutableList<MediaItem>,
                    startIndex: Int,
                    startPositionMs: Long
                ): ListenableFuture<MediaItemsWithStartPosition> {
                    val newItems = mediaItems.map {
                        it.buildUpon().setUri(it.mediaId).build()
                    }.toMutableList()

                    return super.onSetMediaItems(mediaSession, controller, newItems, startIndex, startPositionMs)
                }

                override fun onGetLibraryRoot(session: MediaLibrarySession, browser: MediaSession.ControllerInfo, params: LibraryParams?): ListenableFuture<LibraryResult<MediaItem>> {
                    return Futures.immediateFuture(LibraryResult.ofItem(rootItem, params))
                }

                override fun onGetChildren(
                    session: MediaLibrarySession, browser: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
                    parentId: String, page: Int, pageSize: Int, params: LibraryParams?
                ): ListenableFuture<LibraryResult<ImmutableList<MediaItem>>> {

                    return Futures.immediateFuture(
                        LibraryResult.ofItemList(
                            when (parentId) {
                                nodeROOT -> rootHierarchy
                                nodeTRACKLIST -> tracklist
                                nodePLAYLIST -> playlist
                                else -> rootHierarchy
                            },
                            params
                        )
                    )
                }


                override fun onSubscribe(session: MediaLibrarySession, browser: MediaSession.ControllerInfo, parentId: String, params: LibraryParams?): ListenableFuture<LibraryResult<Void>> {
                    session.notifyChildrenChanged(
                        parentId,
                        when (parentId) {
                            nodeROOT -> 2
                            nodeTRACKLIST -> tracklist.size
                            nodePLAYLIST -> playlist.size
                            else -> 0
                        },
                        params
                    )
                    return Futures.immediateFuture(LibraryResult.ofVoid()) //super.onSubscribe(session, browser, parentId, params)
                }

                /** In order to end the service from our media browser side (UI side), we receive
                 * our own custom command (which is [CUSTOM_COM_END_SERVICE]). However, the session
                 * is not designed to accept foreign weird commands. So we edit the onConnect callback method
                 * to make sure it accepts it.
                 */
                override fun onConnect(session: MediaSession, controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession.ConnectionResult {
                    val sessionComs = super.onConnect(session, controller).availableSessionCommands
                        .buildUpon()
                        .add(CUSTOM_COM_PLAY_ITEM) //Command executed when an item is requested to play
                        .add(CUSTOM_COM_END_SERVICE) //This one is called to end the service manually from the UI
                        .add(CUSTOM_COM_PLAYLIST_ADD) //Command used when adding items to playlist
                        .add(CUSTOM_COM_PLAYLIST_REMOVE) //Command used when removing items from playlist
                        .add(CUSTOM_COM_PLAYLIST_CLEAR) //Command used when clearing all items from playlist
                        .add(CUSTOM_COM_SCAN_MUSIC) //Command use to execute a music scan
                        .add(CUSTOM_COM_TRACKLIST_FORGET) //Used when an item is to be forgotten (swipe left)
                        .build()

                    val playerComs = super.onConnect(session, controller).availablePlayerCommands

                    return MediaSession.ConnectionResult.accept(sessionComs, playerComs)
                }

                /** Receiving some custom commands such as the command that ends the service.
                 * In order to make the player accept newly customized foreign weird commands, we have
                 * to edit the onConnect callback method like we did above */
                override fun onCustomCommand(
                    session: MediaSession,
                    controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
                    customCommand: SessionCommand,
                    args: Bundle
                ): ListenableFuture<SessionResult> {

                    /** When the controller tries to add an item to the playlist */
                    if (customCommand == CUSTOM_COM_PLAY_ITEM) {
                        args.getString("id")?.let { mediaid ->
                            if (args.getBoolean("playlist", false)) {
                                val i = playlist.indexOfFirst { it.mediaId == mediaid }
                                setPlaybackMode(PlayBackMode.PBM_PLAYLIST)
                                player.setMediaItems(playlist, i, 0)
                            } else {
                                val i = tracklist.indexOfFirst { it.mediaId == mediaid }
                                setPlaybackMode(PlayBackMode.PBM_TRACKLIST)
                                player.setMediaItems(tracklist, i, 0)
                            }

                            player.prepare()
                            player.play()
                            return Futures.immediateFuture(SessionResult(RESULT_SUCCESS))

                        }
                    }

                    /** When the controller (like the app) closes fully, we need to disconnect */
                    if (customCommand == CUSTOM_COM_END_SERVICE) {
                        session.release()
                        player.release()
                        this@MusicPlayerService.stopSelf()

                        return Futures.immediateFuture(SessionResult(RESULT_SUCCESS))
                    }

                    /** When the user changes the source folder */
                    if (customCommand == CUSTOM_COM_SCAN_MUSIC) {
                        queryMusic()

                        return Futures.immediateFuture(SessionResult(RESULT_SUCCESS))
                    }

                    /** When the controller tries to add an item to the playlist */
                    if (customCommand == CUSTOM_COM_PLAYLIST_ADD) {
                        args.getString("id")?.let { mediaid ->
                            tracklist.firstOrNull { it.mediaId == mediaid }?.let { itemToAdd ->

                                itemToAdd.playlistFootprint(true)

                                playlist.add(itemToAdd)

                                serviceIOScope.launch {
                                    /** notifying UI-end that the playlist has been modified */
                                    this@MusicPlayerService.session?.apply {
                                        notifyChildrenChanged(
                                            controller,
                                            nodePLAYLIST,
                                            playlist.size,
                                            null
                                        )
                                    }

                                    /** Saving the playlist to memory as it is now */
                                    snapshotPlaylist(playlist)
                                }

                                return Futures.immediateFuture(SessionResult(RESULT_SUCCESS))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /** When the controller tries to remove an item from the playlist */
                    if (customCommand == CUSTOM_COM_PLAYLIST_REMOVE) {
                        args.getString("id")?.let { mediaid ->
                            playlist.firstOrNull { it.mediaId == mediaid }?.let { itemToRemove ->
                                playlist.remove(itemToRemove)

                                serviceIOScope.launch {
                                    /** notifying UI-end that the playlist has been modified */
                                    this@MusicPlayerService.session?.apply {
                                        notifyChildrenChanged(
                                            controller,
                                            nodePLAYLIST,
                                            playlist.size,
                                            null
                                        )
                                    }

                                    /** Saving the playlist to memory as it is now */
                                    snapshotPlaylist(playlist)
                                }

                                return Futures.immediateFuture(SessionResult(RESULT_SUCCESS))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /** When the controller tries to clear the playlist */
                    if (customCommand == CUSTOM_COM_PLAYLIST_CLEAR) {
                        playlist.clear()
                        this@MusicPlayerService.session?.apply {
                            notifyChildrenChanged(
                                controller,
                                nodePLAYLIST,
                                0,
                                null
                            )
                        }

                        /** Saving the playlist to memory as it is now */
                        snapshotPlaylist(playlist)

                        return Futures.immediateFuture(SessionResult(RESULT_SUCCESS))
                    }

                   
                          
                        }
                    }

                    return super.onCustomCommand(session, controller, customCommand, args)
                }
            })
            .build()

    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaLibrarySession? {
        return session
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        snapshotPlaylist(playlist)
        session?.run {
            player.release()
            release()
            session = null
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

**Please note** that some functions are not defined in the reference above, that's because they're not directly relevant to our topic, for example the `scanMusic` call, it's just a function where I query MediaStore and return a lambda with a list of queried mediaitems... So do focus on the actual media3 APIs and how everything is put together